# How does express match a url with the appropriate route?

Tags: node.js, express, url, path

can someone point me to documentation on how express (or any other javascript framework) matches a URL with a route? For example, how does it understand that the following request:

PATCH
https://www.helloworld.com/api/patch/company/1/organization/2/unit/3

should get directed to:

PATCH
https://www.helloworld.com/api/patch/company/:company_id/organization/:organization_id/unit/:unit_id?

I could not find documentation on specifically how to do this.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters.    Express calls the items in the route definition that start with a colon "named parameters".

Here are a few examples from the doc (the first one below is most like the URL you show):

```
Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989
req.params: { "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }

Route path: /flights/:from-:to
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/flights/LAX-SFO
req.params: { "from": "LAX", "to": "SFO" }

Route path: /plantae/:genus.:species
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/plantae/Prunus.persica
req.params: { "genus": "Prunus", "species": "persica" }
```